# Converting datetime to ordinal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, regression

I have a dataframe, which has the dates in Unix encoding, like 1589119704. I have managed to translate the times into day/month/year format. I am building a linear regression, so that after calculating the mean values by days, I have to change the format to ordinal. When I change back the format to normal, so that I can plot the graph or regression, the values are ordered wrong. That means that 1 June is considered to be in the top of the list, even though 1 May should be before. How to solve the wrong conversion and the order so that the dates are ordered correctly? Below is the current code and I have attached the obtained plot which is wrong, because the dates are not in the correct order.[This is the plot of linear regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxfJF.png)

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from distributed.deploy.ssh import bcolors
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime

def create_columns(data):
    data["readable time"] = ""
    data["day"] = ""
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        data.loc[i, ['readable time']] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["time"][i]).strftime(
            '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

        data.loc[i, ['day']] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["time"][i]).strftime(
            '%d/%m/%Y')

def calculate_linear_regression(data, sensor_name):
    create_columns(data)

    print("SORTED",data)
    group_by_df = pd.DataFrame([name, group.mean()[sensor_name]] for name, group in data.groupby('day'))
    group_by_df.columns = ['day', sensor_name]
    group_by_df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(group_by_df['day'],dayfirst=True)
    group_by_df['day'] = group_by_df['day'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)

    def split(group_by_df):
        X = group_by_df[['day']].values
        y = group_by_df[[sensor_name]].values
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)
        return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = split(group_by_df)

    def analyse_forecast():
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "MSE linear regression(mean squared error)",
              mean_squared_error(group_by_df[sensor_name], group_by_df['predicted']), bcolors.ENDC)
        print("r2 score ", r2_score(group_by_df[sensor_name], group_by_df['predicted']))
        rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(group_by_df[sensor_name], group_by_df['predicted']))
        print(bcolors.WARNING + "RMSE for linear regression=", rmse, bcolors.ENDC)
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "MSE TEST ", mean_squared_error(y_test, group_by_df['predicted'][len(X_train):]),
              bcolors.ENDC)
        print("r2 score TEST", r2_score(y_test, group_by_df['predicted'][len(X_train):]))
        return mean_squared_error(group_by_df[sensor_name], group_by_df['predicted'])

    def calculate_linear_reg():
        group_by_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        mse_list = []
        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(group_by_df[['day']])
        group_by_df['predicted'] = y_pred
        mse_list.append(analyse_forecast())

    calculate_linear_reg()

    return group_by_df, X_train, sensor_name


def create_figure(group_by_df, X_train, sensor_name):
    linear_regression_fig = go.Figure()
    # plot predicted values
    linear_regression_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=group_by_df['day'].map(dt.datetime.fromordinal),
        y=group_by_df['predicted'],
        name="linear regression",
        mode='lines+markers',
        marker=dict(
            color=np.where(group_by_df['day'].index < len(X_train), 'red', 'green'))))
    # plot actual values
    linear_regression_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=group_by_df['day'].map(dt.datetime.fromordinal),
        y=group_by_df[sensor_name],
        name='ACTUAL values',
        mode='lines+markers'))

    linear_regression_fig.update_layout(
        height=700,
        font=dict(color="grey"),
        paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        title='Linear regression for ' + sensor_name,
        yaxis_title=sensor_name,
        xaxis_title='Day',
        showlegend=True)
    linear_regression_fig.show()

data=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iulianastroia/csv_data/master/o3_may_june.csv")
group_by_df, X_train, sensor_name = calculate_linear_regression(data, "o3")

linear_reg_fig = create_figure(group_by_df, X_train, sensor_name)
```

Comment: by *Unix encoding* you mean POSIX timestamps (seconds since the epoch)? Why not work with that instead of the ordinal values? Your code seems to contain a lot of stuff that isn't of much relevance to the question, maybe you could focus that a little more, see [mre]?

Comment: @MrFuppes, yes those are Unix encoding. I have tried working with those but the linear regression does not work due to the fact that it calculates values too big.